# Angular 2 - How to Call child component selector inside Tab

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I want to call child component tab inside tab component.

**ParentComponent.html**

```
<tabset>
     <tab *ngFor="let tabz of tabs"
         [heading]="tabz.title"
         [active]="tabz.active"
         (select)="tabz.active = true"
         (deselect)="tabz.active = false"
         [disabled]="tabz.disabled"
         [removable]="tabz.removable"
         (removed)="removeTabHandler(tabz)"
         [customClass]="tabz.customClass">
      {{tabz?.content}}
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

**ParentComponent.ts:**

```
 public tabs: any[] = [
    {title: 'Tab1', content: '<childComponent1> </childComponent1>'},
    {title: 'Tab2', content: '<childComponent2> </childComponent2>', disabled: true},
    {title: 'Tab3', content: '<childComponent3> </childComponent3>', removable: true}
  ];
```

**Childcomponent1.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'childComponent1',
  templateUrl: './childComponent1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./childComponent1.component.scss'],
  providers: [ ComponentService]
})
```

I searched in ng2-bootstrap documentation but they dont have property for selectors. If i give child selector outside of tabset its working not in tabs. Any suggestion on this

Comment: What do you mean by "call a selector". Are you trying to control the tab control from parent?

Comment: Also please take this code `public tabs: any[] = [{title: 'Tab1', content: '<childComponent1> </childComponent1>'}]` and remove the `: any[]` before my blood pressure goes up :p! Type inferences works wonders

Comment: Okey.. I created 4 childcomponent inside one parent module. Parent module component holds tabset. One click of tab i want to load child component content.

Comment: Here selector means accessing to child component html through its selector name. @Component({
  selector: 'childComponent1'}

Comment: Do you mean using jQuery or `document.querySelectorAll`? If so that is wrong for angular.

Comment: No @AluanHaddad I looking for angular selector. Think this wont helps for me. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136509/discussion-between-red-skull-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: Considering using a routed view over this approach. Tab views like this suck to maintain, believe me.